# How to crawl a webpage with selectors?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm crawling a webpage: ogimet.com
This is my code:

```
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

#this path may be different on your cpu, you need to install a browser driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/jcrav/Desktop/driver/chromedriver.exe')
url="http://www.ogimet.com/"
driver.get(url)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver) 
#driver.get(url)

the_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[19]/a')
the_link.click()
time.sleep(2)

desplegable_pais = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('select[name="estado"] option[value="Peru"]')
desplegable_pais.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

The issue is that some selectors does not have a variable named value.
When i select a country, the selector has a variable named value.

```
<option value="Peru">Perú</option>
```

But when i select year, does not have a variable named value

```
<option>2004</option>
```

How can i select a year with the .click command?

Answer (score 1):

use `element.text` for finding what you want

Below is example

```
want_year_num = 2004
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select/option')
for element in elements:
    if element.text == str(want_year_num):
        element.click()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium [Select()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html) class to select item from drop down.

To handle dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

**Code:**

```
driver.get("http://www.ogimet.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sondeos por territorios"))).click()
select=Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='estado']"))))
select.select_by_value('Peru')
selectyear=Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ano']"))))
selectyear.select_by_visible_text('2004')
```

---

However if you still want to use **option** to click item then use this code.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ano']/option[text()='2004']"))).click()
```

---

If you want to parameterize this try below code.

```
year='2004'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='ano']/option[text()='{}']".format(year)))).click()
```

---

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```